# Как работают подприложения в express 4?

Tags: node.js, express

Стоит ли создавать подприложение для админ панели или просто сделать роутер? Что будет более производительно?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста ваш вопрос, приведите пример вашего кода, не понятно что вы хотите узнать и какие у вас уже есть наработки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подприложения - это, фактически, и есть отдельный маршрут. Разница лишь в том, что маршрут всегда сразу завершает обработку запроса - а подприложение содержит отдельную цепочку фильтров и маршрутов.

С точки зрения скорости, подприложение, состоящее из одного-единственного маршрута, работает чуть медленнее, чем этот самый маршрут, заданный напрямую. Но если подприложение содержит несколько маршрутов - то собранные вместе они будут оказывать меньше влияния на производительность, чем сваленные в общую кучу.

Но рассматривать подприложения с точки зрения производительности - это уже микрооптимизации, которые зачастую никому не нужны и выглядят странно. Подприложения обычно используются для других целей.

Механизм подприложений по-настоящему ценен тем, что позволяет вынести настройку части маршрутов в отдельный модуль, поддерживая тем самым порядок в коде и не превращая главный модуль в свалку разнородных маршрутов. Использовать подприложение для админки - хорошая идея.